# Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ; in index.js creat-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, create-react-app

every time I compose react component I make folder for it.
and I make files `index.js` and `component.jsx`

for example

```
├── App.js
├── component
│   ├── index.js
│   └── Component.jsx
...
```

index `component/index.js`

```
export default from './Component'
```

actual react component is written in `Component.jsx`.

but the problem is when I try to build up app with **create-react-app** and import `Component.jsx` like below

```
import Component from './component'
```

error occurs like this

```
./src/component/index.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ; (1:20)

> 1 | export default from './Component'
    |                     ^
  2 |
```

---

but if i write code `component/index.js` like this works well.

```
import Component from './Component'
export default Component
```

is there any problem with my first `index.js`?

Comment: Hello,
did you try appending a ; a the end of your export ?

Comment: Why do you do this? Just curious and trying to learn.

Comment: @tagkiller of course I did so with the second index.js it works well

Comment: @anand I need to write many component. in this case i think it is more comfortable to manage component has its own folder.

Comment: Ok, so why import and reimport. Why not just write within index.js?

Comment: @anand without `index.js` i need to import file lik `./folder/file` but index.js can be resolved by webpack to make simple import i write index.js

Comment: That's why you have the `index.js`. But why the `Component.jsx`?

Comment: @anand I followed airbnb react style guide naming part.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. And that reference is useful. I am reading the style guide right now :)

Comment: @anand would be great if you set up eslint and eslint-airbnb. and if you interested more about formatting code skim [prettier.io](http://prettier.io)

Comment: Thanks! Very valuable. This is what Stack Overflow and 'real people' are for!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this is the way to re export default import as default export,

```
export {default} from './Component'
```

Comment: it works well! thx could you explain why this works and mine isnt working?

Comment: i would appreciate could you give information or es6 spec about this.

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.js`.

> export default from './component'

Comment: I think you get the wrong point. there is only one class component to export

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. Your example does work though in Codesandbox. I would only put it in braces if I need to alias it.

Comment: this is what i did at first. I really dont know why this is not working! wired